# Validating Pin-Pad form using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, jsp, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to input code on a pin pad form available on a website and get it validated. However, I am getting a validation error. I fear the clicked pin buttons are not being read by the website's script. Can anyone help me with this? I am attaching the code as well as the page source code.

**The UI of website looks like this**

[image: The UI looks like this]

The div class on website which contains the keypad is as follows:-

```
     <div class="pin_pad">
        <span id='keypad1' onmouseout="this.className=''" onmouseover="this.className='pin_hover'">1</span>
        <span id='keypad2' onmouseout="this.className=''" onmouseover="this.className='pin_hover'">2</span>
        <span id='keypad3' onmouseout="this.className=''" onmouseover="this.className='pin_hover'">3</span>
        <span id='keypad4' onmouseout="this.className=''" onmouseover="this.className='pin_hover'">4</span>
        <span class="submit_btn" onmouseout="this.className='submit_btn'" onmouseover="this.className='submit_btnpin_hover'" onclick="return validate();">Submit</span>
     </div>
```

My pin is "4444". I am trying to use the .click() method to get "4" clicked. Although I can see that "4" has been clicked 4 times, upon submit, the page shows a validation error. Can anyone help me in solving this problem? Here's my code in python:-

```
pinpad = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pin_pad')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()=4]").click()
for k in range(4):
    actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
    actionChains.context_click(element).perform()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Submit']").submit()
```

Comment: "upon submit, the page shows a validation error." -- the issue, then, is with the website's behavior, not any of the code you've shared. However, I am wondering what you are trying to do with `context_click()`, that should right-click, not left-click, on the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
context_click(element).perform()
```

do this :

```
move_to_element(key4).click().perform()
```

`context_click` is for right click and `move_to_element`() is for moving your mouse cursor to the specify element.

**Brief explanation :**

You can introduce WebDriverWait for more stability,  and I don't think you need to do `context_click()` instead it is `move_to_element()`  plus ActionChains object creation optimization and instead of `submit` you may wanna use `click()`. Check out the code below :

```
pinpad = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pin_pad')
key4 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#keypad4"))).click()
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
for k in range(4):
    actionChains.move_to_element(key4).click().perform()
    sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Submit']"))).click()
```